# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout: ProgressBar not show above MaterialButton

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Android Studio 3.2.1

In my build.gradle:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>


    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/jsonViewToolBar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:title='@{@string/add_trader}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/base"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jsonViewToolBar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/baseEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quoteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseEditText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quoteEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteTextView" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteEditText" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here **progress_bar_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/containerProgressBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4777"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/min_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result:

[image]

Why `ProgressBar` is **UNDER** `MaterialButton` ?

Comment: Did you try to set the `elevation` property on your `ProgressBar`?

Comment: missing layout constraint under element  `include layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout"...`

Comment: @FonzTech I use "android:elevation="10dp" for ProgressBar. It's not help.

Comment: @jackycflau What do you mean?

Comment: constraints for the included layout are missing that is what @jackycflau is trying to point.That might be causing a misplaced progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the elevation of the progress bar set to `10dp` and that is getting to the right answer but, because the progress bar is embedded in a `ConstraintLayout` and the `ConstraintLayout` is included in another layout, it is the `ConstraintLayout` that needs the elevation.

Simply move `android:elevation="10dp"` from the `ProgressBar` to its enclosing `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: What about Android 5.0 ? "android:elevation" is only from  API>= 21

Comment: @Alexei In that case, make sure that the layout with the progress bar is included after the material button. Views are drawn in order of their appearance in the layout (usually), so the button will be drawn and then the progress bar will be drawn on top of it.

Comment: @Alexei If you remove the elevation from the button, you will miss out on one of the "material" aspects of the button.

Answer (score 1):

To make the button, unelevated button you can add the style attribute as below:-

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
```